# Extract Embedding from GCMLE Saved Model

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-cloud-ml

I am trying to download embeddings from a trained GCMLE prediction model locally so that I can play with my own custom embedding visualizations that aren't available in tensorboard. I'd like to extract these embeddings into a largy numpy matrix, but I'm having trouble with a few steps. I can successfully download all of the files (`saved_model.pb` + `assets/*` + `variables/*`, and I appear to be able to restore the model with the following code:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess,[tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], _EXPORT_DIR)
```

which successfully returns:

`INFO:tensorflow:Restoring parameters from Servo/variables/variables`

I then tried to extract the weights like this:

```
constant_values = {}

with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], _EXPORT_DIR)

    constant_ops = [op for op in sess.graph.get_operations() if op.type == "Const"]
    for constant_op in constant_ops:
        constant_values[constant_op.name] = sess.run(constant_op.outputs[0])
```

which did succesfully output quite a lot, but the only parts relevant to the embedding were:

```
u'embedding_layer/embeddings/Initializer/random_uniform/max': 0.012765553,
u'embedding_layer/embeddings/Initializer/random_uniform/min': -0.012765553,
u'embedding_layer/embeddings/Initializer/random_uniform/shape': array([vocab_size, word_embedding_size], dtype=int32)
```

and no sign of the actual embedding weights. How can I modify my approach above to get the actual embedding weight matrix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will depend a bit on how you exported model, but in most cases, the embeddings are Variables and not constants. So you want something like:

```
with tf.Session(graph=tf.Graph()) as sess:
    tf.saved_model.loader.load(sess, [tf.saved_model.tag_constants.SERVING], _EXPORT_DIR)

    trainable_coll = sess.graph.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES)
    vars = {v.name:sess.run(v.value()) for v in trainable_coll}
```

Comment: Very neat - that makes a lot more sense. I thought I had read that they would all become constants for SERVING, but guess I made that up. I got the warning that `VARIABLES` was deprecated, and based on this: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys I thought that `MODEL_VARIABLES` would have the "subset of objects that are used in the model for inference" but it was empty when I used MODEL_VARIABLES. Is there any way to restrict this to just the inference variables?

Comment: Seems like TRAINABLE_VARIABLES would contain anything needed at inference time

Comment: TRAINABLE_VARIABLES is indeed correct. I'll update the post.

Comment: RE: constants, you can "freeze" the graph (convert variables to constants), but that is currently done post-hoc rather than during export.